# Custom Elements images are blurry Android

Tags: android

I'm having some issues creating custom elements in Android layout.
I have a `CheckBox` and an `EditText`, I've created a custom `CheckBox` image (for state ON and OFF) and a custom LeftView image for my `EditText`, the size of the images I've created is the same of the checkboxes but when I run the app the images are blurry and low-quality.

To set the `EditText's` LeftView I used:

```
 android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user_icon"
```

And for the custom `CheckBox` image I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/check_on" />
         <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/check_off" />
    </selector>
```

Am I missing something? I can't create larger images because the elements size will just resize to the content and if I set it to be lower than the image size the image will get cut out (from top and bottom)

Answer (score 0):

You should create your images with appropriate sizes (i.e. checkbox hdpi image should be 32x32px etc.) and put them in matching drawable-?dpi folders. If you create one big image for all densities it will be scaled down and that often ends up looking the way you describe

Comment: oh damn, I thought It wasn't like IOS.. So for example if my checkbox image is 20x20 what size should I create for the other folder?